# ArcPy remove rows which don't match a list of substrings

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor

I'm trying to use ArcPy to remove results of an OD cost matrix which don't have specific street names. I have the street names stored in a list and the OD results in a field called "Name" as shown below.
[image: OD matrix Name field]

```
names = ["Bridge Rd & 3rd Line","Bridge Rd & Stanfield Dr","Bridge Rd & Lees Ln"]
```

I've tried using the following ArcPy script but it ends up deleting all rows in the input file.

```
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("OD_Results.shp","Name") as cursor:
       for element in names:
          for row in cursor:
              if row[0] != element:
                 cursor.deleteRow()
       arcpy.AddMessage("Finished.")
```

The desired output would only include values in the Name field which are present in the names list.

Update: I've been trying the following code, but it crashes ArcMap each time it runs:

```
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("OD_Results.shp","Name") as cursor:
       for row in cursor:
           for name in names:
               if name not in row[0]:
                      cursor.deleteRow()
```

Comment: Your current logic doesn't use the cursor correctly (you only get one pass) or the NOT EQUALS relationship with respect to set members (none of the listed names are equal). Use Select By Attributes and Delete Rows instead.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide an example of the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

Your updated answer is almost right.

That code will work :

```py
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("OD_Results.shp","Name") as cursor:
       for row in cursor:
           delete_row = True
           for name in names:
               if name in row[0]:
                   delete_row = False
                   break
           if delete_row:
               cursor.deleteRow()
```

Without the `break` statement, your second loop may try to delete the current row a second time, leading to a bug.

You can also use the `any` statement:

```py
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("OD_Results.shp","Name") as cursor:
       for row in cursor:
           if not any(name in row[0] for name in names):
               cursor.deleteRow()
```

Comment: Nice use of the `any()` function, not something I have used before, thanks!

Comment: If I'm interpreting this right, the first code block is not quite accurate, because if the "street you want to find" is not in the first item in the name list, it will delete the row without checking the rest of the name list...

Comment: I very much like the second code block, I'll be starting to use any() as well... :)

Comment: Yeah that's true for the first code block, I will change that

Answer (score 2):

Credit to @BERA I'm just repurposing his deleted answer.

Use a where clause to return only the rows you want to delete:

```py
import arcpy

shapefile = r"C:\folder\OD_Results.shp"    
where_clause = "Name LIKE '%Bridge Rd & 3rd Line%' OR Name LIKE '%Bridge Rd & Stanfield Dr%' OR Name LIKE '%Bridge Rd & Lees Ln%'"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shapefile,"Name", where_clause) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        cursor.deleteRow()
```

Be aware that the where [clause uses a dialect of SQL](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/building-a-query-expression.htm) that is used by shapefiles, so if your data was in a file geodatabase the syntax would be slightly different.

Comment: The logic for this answer is completely opposite of what the OP wanted... you are selecting all the rows that the user wants to keep, but then you're deleting them, leaving only the rows that the OP wants to get rid of... Also, the cursor.deleteRow() does not take any arguments...

Comment: To use the where_clause (for this example), you would change it to something like:   "Name NOT LIKE '%Bridge Rd & 3rd Line%' AND Name NOT LIKE '%Bridge Rd & Stanfield Dr%' AND Name NOT LIKE '%Bridge Rd & Lees Ln%'"   For three entries like this example it's not terrible, but if you have 10, 50, more names it becomes unwieldy... which is why I structured my answer as I did...

Comment: @JasonMiller I read the original question as they did want to delete the rows, and your additional comment of what the where clause should be offers that alternative. I have corrected my code and removed that erroneous argument. I think our solutions compliment each other and importantly show alternate ways of doing the same thing; yours is a more flexible approach whilst I feel mine is more succinct, but as you say currently OK because it queries only a few fields, any more and it starts to become unwieldy.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers technically meet your requirements but all suffer from the same potential issue: they would also match *partial* location names.

For example, you want to keep rows with the location "Bridge Rd & 3rd Line", but if a row contained "Covered Bridge Rd & 3rd Linebacker St" then this would also match.  This might be unlikely and may never occur in your specific dataset, but it's always good to think through potential pitfalls.

I'd suggest working with the full location identifiers instead of partial strings, i.e. including the "Oakville, Ontario, L6L" part in the comparisons.  We can also use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) to make sure performance doesn't suffer:

```py
locs_keep = {
    "Bridge Rd & 3rd Line, Oakville, Ontario, L6L",
    "Bridge Rd & Stanfield Dr, Oakville, Ontario, L6L",
    "Bridge Rd & Lees Ln, Oakville, Ontario, L6L"
}

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("OD_Results.shp", "Name") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # split apart the "from" and "to" locations
        locs_row = set(row[0].split(" - "))
        # test the assumption that " - " only appears as the from/to delimiter
        assert len(locs_row) == 2
        # set intersection; create a new set with common elements
        locs_common = locs_keep & locs_row
        # if there are no common elements then delete the row
        if not locs_common:
            cursor.deleteRow()
```

(untested)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work...

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("OD_Results.shp", "LSN") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        bKeepThisRow = False
        for name in names:
            if name in row[0]:
                bKeepThisRow = True

        if bKeepThisRow == False:
            cursor.deleteRow()
```